# Canvas Text with two different font size in the same sentence

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

Canvas Text with two different font size in the same sentence side by side
Is there a way I can achieve this?

```
   ctx.textAlign = left;
   ctx.font = "bold 20px ";
   ctx.fillStyle = '#ccc';
   ctx.fillText("Normal Small", 100, 300);
```

[image]

Comment: You want to use [`measureText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText) somewhere. Have you tried this?

Comment: You have to use two different fillTexts

Comment: @user4642212 I am new to the canvas so is there an example I can piggy back on?

Comment: @Kudlas I am not sure if it would be efficient as html. Please provide an example if you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Simple canvas markup

You can define your own markup format and then render the text depending on the markup rules.

For example a string `"This is normal, <b>this is bold</b> and back to normal."`

Where the tags `<b>` and `</b>` define the start and end of the bold section of text.

You then iterate the string breaking it into parts depending on the location of tags. Rather than use RegExp I will search manually and use a stack to keep track of nested styles.

To define style you can just create an object that maps the style via a single character

```
const styles = {
    default: { font: "16px arial", fillStyle: "black", },
    b: { font: "16px arial black", fillStyle: "black", },
    w: { fillStyle: "white" },
};
```

The styles are set using `Object.assign(ctx, styles["b"])`

#### Example

The function `canvasMarkupText(ctx, str, x, y, styles)` renders text using a simple markup and scheme `styles`.

- It creates a stack, that holds a content object which holds the string position and rule name,
- A render function that will render the details in a content object,
- A simple iterator (while loop) that controls when content is added and removed from the stack, and when to render content.
- Before exit it checks if the stack has content and renders an remaining text.
- The function returns the width of rendered text.

**Note** There is no validation of the markup.

**Note** Styles cascade down but not up.

**Note** This example will only work with single character tags.

**Note** The use of `"<"` in the example as markup delimiter means the function can not render that character. To do so you will need to add some form of escape sequence. eg double `"<<"` can represent that character.

This is an example ONLY and is not meant as a solution. Use it as a guide to build your own.

```js
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const styles = {
    default: {font: "14px arial", fillStyle: "black",},
    b: {font: "14px arial black", fillStyle: "black",},
    w: {fillStyle: "white"},
};

canvasMarkupText(ctx, "Testing <b>testing BOLD <w>bold white</w></b> and testing with default <w>and white</w>", 10, 14, styles)

function canvasMarkupText(ctx, str, x, y, styles) {
    const content = (start, end, rule) => ({start, end, rule});
    const render = content => {
        Object.assign(ctx, styles[content.rule] ? styles[content.rule] : {});
        const s = str.slice(content.start, content.end)
        ctx.fillText(s, x, y);
        x += ctx.measureText(s).width;
    };

    const stack = [], xx = x;
    var pos = 0, current = content(pos, pos, "default");
    stack.push(current);
    while (pos < str.length) {
        const c = str[pos++];
        if (c === "<") {
           if (str[pos] === "/") {
               render(stack.pop());
               current = stack[stack.length - 1];
               current.start = current.end = (pos += 3);
           } else {
               render(current);
               pos += 2;
               stack.push(current = content(pos, pos, str[pos - 2]));
           }
        } else { current.end = pos }
    }
    stack.length && render(current);
    return x - xx;
}
```

```css
canvas {background: #59D}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="20"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also tried @BlindMan67 suggestion
And did this:

```
           ctx.textAlign = align;
           ctx.font = "bold 20px " + this.fontStyle;
           ctx.fillStyle = this.rewardsTextColor;

           var ctxTextYPlacement = (this.gaugeCenterY - coord.y) - 5;
           var ctxTextXPlacement = this.gaugeCenterX - coord.x - 12;

           ctx.fillText(earningValue, ctxTextXPlacement, ctxTextYPlacement);

           var measure = ctx.measureText(earningValue);
           var measureWidth = measure.width - 30;

           ctx.font = "bold 10px " + this.fontStyle;
           ctx.fillText('mi.', (ctxTextXPlacement + measureWidth), ctxTextYPlacement);
```